# Как подключить js файлы в Gulp?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

Всем привет! Пытаюсь разобраться с Gulp и столкнулся с такой проблемой: .js файл выгружается в dist, но скрипт файла не запускается, а HTML, CSS отображаются нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

.js файл

```
console.log('Hello');
```

gulpfile.js файл

```
const webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    'clean',
    gulp.parallel('html', 'sass', 'images', 'js'),
    gulp.parallel('server', 'watch')
));
```

webpack.config.js файл

```
const config = {

    mode: 'production',

    entry: {
        index: './src/js/index.js',
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

И в index.html я подключаю скрипт

```
<scrip src="./js/index.bundle.js"></scrip>
```

Все запускается, но в консоле строка 'Hello' не выводится. Вот результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может ошибка в пропущенной букве? `<script src="./js/index.bundle.js"></script>`. А возможно и в том, что используется два сборщика одновременно :\

Comment: Вы правильно заметили. Спасибо большое. Оказывается тег "script" не правильно написал и ни никак не мог заметить это. Теперь все работает